# xubuntu launches applications at startup that are not in the application startup settings

Tags: ubuntu, startup, xubuntu

At startup, my computer launches a number of applications that are not in the session & startup / Application Autostart setting: Okular, terminal, truecrypt. These applications were not necessarily open at shutdown.

Xubuntu system: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit, xcfe version 4.10.

How do I disable automatic startup of these applications, while they are not in the startup setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because your session was saved with these applications opened. Cleaning ~/.cache/sessions dir should help.